# Use GCMIntentService or GCMBroadcastReceiver to post a statusbar notice?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to setup GCM to post a statusbar notification when a message is sent to my app.  When the notifcation is pressed, it should launch the app to actually retrieve the message.  What I'm having trouble with is trying to decide how to intercept and process the incoming GCM messages.  The app may not be running at the time the GCM message is received so I think I need a GCMIntentService to receive the GCM message and post a notification to the statusbar.  Does this sound right? Launching the app when pressing the statusbar notification is done by the way the notification is setup?  Is that right, or is a custom broadcastreceiver needed to receive the statusbar notification click?  I need answers to the overall design question before getting into implementation details.  I've already got AndroidManifest.xml setup and MainActivity.java setup with registering with GCM, but I still need to know how to design incoming message handling.  The key points are that the app may not be running but the message must still go to the statusbar, then clicking the notification launches the app.  Also, the app shouldn't be killed when the broadcastreceiver is killed, so the broadcasterreceiver must be separate.

After this lengthy question I hope you're still with me and have some advice on how to set this up.  I can post what code I've got so far if that helps. Thanks.

UPDATE:
It appears as though I may want to use a GCMIntentService to post the notification in the onMessage() function.  Comments?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.pictureplay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.pictureplay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.pictureplay.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Did you read the GCM docs? Everything you need is there.

Comment: I've read it a dozen times but still missing pieces. The docs are fragmented and don't always pertain to my usage.

Answer (score 0):

> The app may not be running at the time the GCM message is received so I think I need a GCMIntentService to receive the GCM message and post a notification to the statusbar. Does this sound right?

No, in part because there is no `GCMIntentService`, unless you write your own class by that name.

Posting a `Notification` is fairly quick, if your app does not need to do disk I/O to get the data to display in the `Notification`. You can safely do quick things from a `BroadcastReceiver` and its `onReceive()` method. Your GCM message is delivered to your broadcast receiver (see [the GCM docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#manifest), sixth bullet down).

> Also, the app shouldn't be killed when the broadcastreceiver is killed, so the broadcasterreceiver must be separate.

A `BroadcastReceiver` is not "killed" in any conventional Android use of the term "killed".

Comment: If the BroadcastReceiver isn't running when GCM needs to send it a message (because the app isn't running) will GCM still know to send to the BR? That's why I thought I needed a service. I've tried this with Parse.com and if the Parse service isn't awake, the push never gets received. I added my AndroidManifest entries above if that helps.  The comment about killed came from, " if that process was only hosting the BroadcastReceiver  the system will consider its process to be empty and aggressively kill it so that resources are available for other more important processes" from Google docs

Comment: @user2431174: "If the BroadcastReceiver isn't running" -- manifest-registered `BroadcastReceivers` are created as needed, used for one broadcast, and are discarded. "will GCM still know to send the BR" -- yes.